# Google Sheets Query want to ask user to enter a contains field

Tags: google-sheets, substitution, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Some of the data they want to search contains a `'` and my code looks like this

```
=query(Sheet1!A:A,"select * where upper(A) contains '"&upper(A1)&"'")
```

Some sample search they might type in A1 is

```
Test' Bob
1274'2134
asd''asd
test2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(A:B, "'", "♦"), 
 "where upper(Col1) contains '"&SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(D1), "'", "♦")&"'", 0), "♦", "'"))
```

[image: 0]